# C++ stack allocated object, explicit destructor call

Tags: c++, stl, destructor

I came across a strange use of the destructor while working on an existing library. The destructor of a stack allocated stl vector was being called explicitly, when its the case that that object may need to be used again. These vector objects are a slightly customised version of the stl vector class that have a specialized `clear` method. In the destructor body there exist two method calls: `clear()`, `_Tidy()`.

I've been trying to think of a good reason why this destructor is being called rather than just `clear` but I'm at a loss. Anyone shed any light on why this may be a good idea?

Comment: Can you provide a code sample, of the vectors dtor, and how it is called?

Comment: Show us how the vector was created.

Comment: The vector was created using the default constructor, by a simple declaration. _Tidy() releases the memory as far as I am aware.

An example:
CustomVector<Value> vector;

...

later
vector.~CustomVector();

Comment: "The vector was created using the default constructor, by a simple declaration." If so (I suppose you meant _definition_), then explicitly calling its dtor should only be done for very good reason and with great care.

Answer (score 10):

clear() isn't guaranteed to actually release the allocated storage in the vector; _Tidy() in the MSVC implementation will actually free that storage, so this was probably done as an optimization.

It's an evil thing to do, but you can do it legally (without undefined behavior) so long as the storage is reused by an object of the same type (ignoring cv-qualifiers) that takes up exactly all of the storage:

```
T automatic;
automatic.T::~T();
new (&automatic) T();
```

Section 3.8.7 of the C++ standard describes this usage scenario and explains how it's legal; it even includes an example that is similar to the above.

Answer (score 6):

Could this class use some kind of [placement new](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10) method?  That's the only time I tend to see explicit destructors in use.

Comment: Beat me to the punch while I was writing. ;)

Answer (score 6):

Large vector?

Wild guess... when `clear()` is called the vector is usually emptied but the memory not released. That is why there's the pattern

```
std::vector<T>().swap(vector_to_clear);
```

to empty the vector for reuse and clear the allocated memory.

Perhaps the original author did not know the pattern and tried to get rid of the allocated memory in this wicked fashion. (I think `_Tidy` frees the allocated memory)

Comment: The vectors vary in size but none eroneously large.

I would love to know the original authors intent on this, and hopefully it was just a misguided memory deallocation

Comment: My first question is such situations is: What's the checkin comment?

Answer (score 2):

It's definitely not a good idea. Any operation on an object after the destructor starts running yields undefined behavior.

Comment: Or rather, after the destructor finishes? I suppose it might be valid if you construct another instance at the same place with placement new before doing anything else with the instance and before it goes out of scope.

Comment: And these operations include the dtor being automatically invoked at the end of the scope.

Comment: @UncleBens: no, as soon as the destructor starts you should consider your object no longer exists... try using virtual functions from a destructor of a base class that actually use a heap-allocated memory of the derived class... see what I mean :) ?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the original coder cared about where in memory the objects were allocated.

Then the destructor must be called explicitly, as per [this discussion](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/dtors.html#faq-11.10).

Comment: Which is probably the case since the discussion is about a stack-allocated vector.