# Deducing template type of object while this object is being destroyed

Tags: c++, templates

Situation: I have a deque declared as `deque<intmax_t> tab` and i want to destroy it with deduced template argument. I tried `tab.~deque<__decltype(tab.at(0))>()` which gives me the compiler error:

```
Csrt.cpp: In function 'int main(int32_t, char**)':
Csrt.cpp:303:34: the type being destroyed is 'std::deque<long long int>',
 but the destructor refers to 'std::deque<long long int&>'
  tab.~deque<__decltype(tab.at(0))>();
                                  ^
```

The question is: is something like that doable?

What I know I do not want to do: create dummy variables. Like: `auto dummy = tab.at(0)`
What I hope is doable: one-line destructor.

What i tried, too: `tab.~deque<__decltype(tab[0])>()` with result: same as above.

I think that is all information needed. Thank you in advance.

Comment: If you really need to call the destructor with a type parameter a quick fix would be to do something like `std::decay<decltype(tab[0])>::type`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that the `at` member function in deque is defined like this:

```
intmax_t &at(size_t pos);
```

So your `decltype(x.at(0))` actually resolves to `intmax_t&`.

You can use the `remove_reference` type trait:

```
#include <type_traits>
x.~deque<std::remove_reference<decltype(x.at(0))>::type>();
```

But it is easier if you use the helpful member typedefs available in every standard container:

```
x.~deque<decltype(x)::value_type>();
```

Naturally, for this particular case, I think that you can just use the injected class name for the destructor:

```
x.~deque();
```

Answer (score 2):

You're calling the destructor on a stack-based object, so I take it you're interested in using placement new later on, similar to this SO post [C++ stack allocated object, explicit destructor call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1638438/c-stack-allocated-object-explicit-destructor-call).

Using g++ 4.4.3 on Ubuntu 10.04, simply using the desctructor without template embellishments compiles and runs for me:

```
tab.~deque();
```

Is there something I'm missing?

---

I can't comment on other's posts yet, but [rodrigo's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/865874/rodrigo) answer is great. Further to that, here is a rather long but informative SO post on the topic of [explicit destructors in templated contexts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6845779/explicit-destructor-in-templated-context).

Answer (score 1):

It's usually easier to write a function to deduce a type than try to specify it yourself. How about:

```
template <typename T>
void murder(T& t)
{ t.~T(); }
```

In C++11, you can just use the injected class name:

```
tab.~deque();
```